# How can I translate けど in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, particles

I don't get these sentences; the first one ends with けど (plus I don't get why there is the use of !? at the end)

Here the sentences:

> 俺モデル!
>   顔命なの です
>   けど!?
>
> んなに
>   硬くねーだろ>

I know that けど means "but, though, however" but I don't get the meaning here.

My translation is:

"I am a model! My face is the most important thing but!?" (there's a pause here before the person continues talking)

"It isn't so hard"

But the second sentence kind of make no sense to me unless けど at the end changes the entire meaning of the second sentence? So that the translation is completely different?

The context is (if this can help) the person has been hit by a ball in the face and he is angry and shouting.
Help would be much appreciated (:

Comment: I think the けど is #2-1 in http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/68969/m0u/ or #3-1-㋑or㋒ in http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/34931/m0u/%E3%81%8C/ でももう少し強い感じですよね

Comment: Are both sentences said by the same person? (I first thought the second sentence was saying "The ball is not that hard, is it?" as a response to "Hey, I'm a model, so my face is very important, you know!"...) Anyway I think the「けど」is like... 「～けど、わかってんの？」with a kind of criticizing tone.

Comment: Yes, they are both said by the same person^^ I am still confused by it though^^ thanks for the help anyway c:

Comment: Is this a video or a book/manga? Can you link to the source? I cannot tell if katai refers to the ball or to his life.

Answer (score 1):

I think the translation of "けど" here is "although, yet" not "but, however". But I haven't understood the beginning of the second sentence. Could you write in romaji too or add furigana above kanjis.(Sorry I cannot read kanjis without furigana, I only know japanese by ear :) )

I think it will be something like this as much as I understand;)

I'm a model! Although my face is (my/the) most important thing (of a model's), .....

If you write furigana/in romaji I'd more helpful :)

Comment: I am confused more than ever now o.o Anyway the sentence in romaji would be: (sorry I am not really used writing in romaji^^) "ore moderu! kao inochi nano desu kedo!?" "nnani kata kune daro" nnani is short for sonnani if this helps c

Answer (score 0):

May I offer a very contextualized quote:

`I'm pretty sure there's a lot more to life than being really, really, ridiculously good looking. And I plan on finding out what that is.`

– [Derek Zoolander](http://www.zimbio.com/Zoolander+Quotes)

Here, your `けど` roughly maps to the almost-modestness of `I'm pretty sure`. It is more of a modal modifier than a grammatical thing.

`硬くねーだろ` is an idiomatic response, with 硬い referring to 硬派-ness (hardliner-ness), i.e. playfully doubting that the recipient "is up to it".

Comment: given your explanation how would you translate the second sentence related to the first one? =O

Comment: You're pretty much free in choice of words for the English utterance. "You can't be serious", "No shit?", or "You mean that butt above your neck?" – whatever fits the character.
Instead of the model aspect, the 2nd person could also be referring to the inaptness to play the ball game they are engaged in, in which case you might translate it as "Are you even trying?" etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming, without adequate knowledge of the full context, that 硬い refers to the hardness of the ball. Though in English, "hard," can refer figuratively to the difficulty of say, life, for instance, in Japanese I do not think 硬い is used as commonly in an analogous manner. Though perhaps as Jens says, it refers to  硬派?

Here is my attempt at translation:

> 俺モデル! 顔命なの です けど!?
>   I'm a model! (*I'm reacting this way because)My face is my life!?
>
> んなに 硬くねーだろ>
>   Ok, so it's not that hard...(referring to the ball)

です けど at the end of an exclamation can sometimes take the meaning of, "..it's just because..," and in this instance may be an apology of sorts, or a way to explain his reaction and give an excuse.

The use of the question mark here may be more akin to grawlix commonly seen in comics, signifying confusion or surprise, rather than a question. The use of roman symbols such as the question mark are not as codified in Japanese as they are in English.

A few examples of similar uses of ですけど can be found in this link:

http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=ですけど%21&ref=sa

Comment: thank you for the accurate explanation, and yes I think that 硬く refers to the ball, there is no way that sentence would make sense otherwise. I was also confused by the question mark at the end of けど. However everything is clear now thanks everyone for the answers c: